# PostgreSQL: Set-retuning functions are not allowed in JOIN conditions

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, inner-join, sql-like

I have two tables that I need to join.  One table (call it table A) contains the letter code of a product in a field called "ProductCode".  The other table (table B) contains the same letter code with a bunch of numbers attached to it, so I am extracting it using REGEXP_MATCHES(B.ProductCode,'([A-Za-z])','g'))[1].  Then I try to join the two tables like so:

```
select * from A
inner join B on A.ProductCode = REGEXP_MATCHES(B.ProductCode,'([A-Za-z])','g'))[1]
```

So for example:

```
Table A:
----------------------
Product Code | Sales
----------------------
A            | 100
B            | 200


  Table B:
---------------------
Product Code | Region
---------------------
A234         | Midwest
B543         | Southwest
```

The desired result of the join above would be:

```
------------------------------
Product Code | Sales | Region
----------------------------
A            | 100   | Midwest
B            | 200   | Southwest
```

But I am getting the error: 'Set-returning functions are not allowed in JOIN conditions'.

I get it that REGEXP_MATCHES returns an array, but I am extracting an element of that array ([1]), so it should no longer be a set?   Not sure how to fix it.   Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Please show us a few rows of sample data from both tables, and the corresponding desired result.

Comment: Just did above, thank you

Comment: regexp_matches returns a set of arrays.  It is the "set of", not the array, which is the problem here.  Subscripting it turns it from a set of arrays, to a set of scalars.  Could you just use `regexp_match` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this sample data, a regexp seems overkill. You could just use `substring()`, or `like`:

```
select a.*, b.region
from a
inner join b on b.product_code like a.product_code || '%'
```